# TypeScript: Elegant Way to Infer Type to Array Square Brackets []

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics

Can I put this into one line?:

```
    const arr:Array<number> = []
    setIndices(arr.concat(indices.slice(0, current), current, indices.slice(current, indices.length)))
```

The arr constant remains unused here.

I tried the following:

```
    setIndices([].concat(indices.slice(0, current), current, indices.slice(current, indices.length)))
```

-> "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'."

Can I infer a type to square brackets [] like so: `[]<number>` or so `[].concat<number>`?

Comment: It's probably clearer if you keep it on two lines

Answer (score 1):

Before this...

```
    setIndices((new Array<number>()).concat(indices.slice(0, current), current, indices.slice(current, indices.length)))
```

...I finally came to this:

```
    setIndices(([] as number[]).concat(indices.slice(0, current), current, indices.slice(current, indices.length)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```js
setIndices((<number[]>[]).concat(indices.slice(0, current), current, indices.slice(current, indices.length)))
```